# How to remove bottom controls from react-native-video

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, react-native-video

Currently I have a react-native-video component that is taking my video from my local file. I have a problem with my current Video component. My current layout is in such a way that the videos controls(play, pause, forward) are overlapping with my bottom text. So I want to have those controls fit inside my actual video: This is how it currently looks:

[image]

And this is the current code:

```
<Video
            resizeMode='contain'
            source={fishVideo}
            style={{width: 457, height: 264}}
            controls={true}
            ref={ref => {
              this.player = ref;
            }}
            // hideControls:true
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give **controls** as false:

```
controls={false}
```